# Change in order of duplicates after sorting by Quicksort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I read somewhere(apologies that I do not remember where) that a correct sorting algorithm should sort the duplicate values in the order in which they appear in unsorted sequence.

Example:

> 5(A), 2, 4, 5(B), 6, 5(C), 1, 3

5(A/B/C) : Here A, B & C is used just to denote the ordering of 5's.

5(A) : First 5 out of three 5's

5(B) : Second 5 out of three 5's

5(C) : Third 5 out of three 5's

After sorting, the above list should be:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5(A), 5(B), 5(C), 6

But Quicksort gives the following sorted sequence:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5(C), 5(A), 5(B), 6

**Code :**

```
void sort(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex){
            int right = endIndex;
            int pivot = array[(startIndex+endIndex)/2];
            int left = startIndex;
            int temp;
            while(left <= right){ 
                while(array[right] > pivot){
                    right--;
                }
                while(array[left] < pivot){
                    left++;
                }
                if(left <= right){
                    temp = array[right];
                    array[right] = array[left];
                    array[left] = temp;
                    left++;
                    right--;
                }
            }
            if(startIndex < right) {
                sort(array, startIndex, right);
            }
            if(endIndex > left) {
                sort(array, left, endIndex);
            }
    }
```

Is this behavior correct? If not, then what can be done to have the correct output in which ordering of duplicate elements are same as in unsorted sequence?

EDIT:

An algorithm which maintains relative ordering of duplicate elements is called ['Stable sort'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) as informed by Dukeling in comments.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) tells us a sorting algorithm that maintains relative order of equal items is called "stable". Highly related or duplicate: [Quicksort - conditions that makes it stable.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804115/quicksort-conditions-that-makes-it-stable)

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you for this information. Any idea how we can make stable Quicksort?

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for pointing the mistake. Quicksort in its efficient implementation can't be made stable indeed.

Comment: The question linked above, and [the question linked from there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278243/stability-of-quicksort-partitioning-approach) mention a few alternatives: (a) store and consider the original index of each element when comparing elements, meaning elements with equal keys will no longer be considered equal, (b) quicksort on a linked-list, (c) using O(n) extra space - create a temp array and instead of swapping, go once from each side, adding smaller / bigger elements to the correct side of the temp array in order, then copy it back (or other methods might work too).

Answer (score 2):

Quicksort is not a stable algorithm.  If you want the sorting order to be preserved, use a stable algorithm.  Mergesort is a stable sorting algorithm.