# Can quicksort ever be stable?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, stability

If values equal to the pivot are also considered during quicksort can it be called a stable sort? Here is my implementation of quicksort:

```
def isOrdered(aList):
ordered = True
for i in range(len(aList)-1):
    if aList[i] > aList[i+1]:
        ordered = False
        break
return ordered

def partition(List,pivotIndex):
    pivot=List[pivotIndex]
    less=[]
    equal=[]
    greater=[]
    if pivotIndex<len(List):
        for i in List:
            if i<pivot:
                less.append(i)
            elif i==pivot:
                equal.append(i)
            else:
                greater.append(i)
    returnlist= [less,equal,greater]
    return returnlist

def quicksort(List,pivotIndex=0):
    sortedList = []
    if pivotIndex>=len(List):
        pivotIndex%=len(List)
    for i in partition(List,pivotIndex):
        for j in i:
            sortedList.append(j)
    pivotIndex+=1
    if isOrdered(sortedList):
        return sortedList
    else:
        return quicksort(sortedList,pivotIndex)
```

Is it possible to improve stability and maintain computational speed for quicksort at the same time?

Comment: Is this a [homework question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2305521)?

Comment: There's no way to change the partitioning method to guarantee Quicksort's stability. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278243/stability-of-quicksort-partitioning-approach and related questions (links on the right) for more information about why that is, and for suggestions how to change the algorithm to make it stable.

Comment: @JimMischel "There's no way to change the partitioning method to guarantee Quicksort's stability."  That's a very strong claim, and I don't see it supported by the link you gave, nor any links that I followed on the right (of this question, or that one).  The fact that many variations of the partitioning method are unstable isn't evidence, of course.  Do you have a more specific link or argument to back up your claim?